# Javascript: importing React from Electron renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am using VSCode on Windows. I have set up a boilerplate ElectronJS app and want to use React for the UI. I have `main.js`, `index.html`, `preload.js` and `renderer.js`.

I have installed these and other packages (like `babel`) via `npm`. I see react and other packages in `node_modules/` however I can't figure out how to get React imported.

Here is my project structure

```
node_modules/
.gitignore
index.html
main.js
preload.js
renderer.js
```

In my `renderer.js` file I have done as I see other people demonstrate:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

In the Electron app's developer console I see: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

So I have switched to:

```
import React from './node_modules/react'
```

(In the dev console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

For all of these options (separately!):

```
import React from './node_modules/react/index.js'
import React from './node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js';
import React from import React from './node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js';
```

(because it looks like that file reads a Node environment variable to export up either the Dev or Prod version, so it seemed like it might be my entry point) I get "The requested module ... does not provide an export named 'default'.

Comment: The solution was recognizing that these files coming from npm seem to be for use within a node environment, not a browser. I added lines to my build-dev script in package.json (which transpiles JSX with babel) to also wget -nc the dev/prod versions of CDN-hosted React files, and that is working.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```